# getWidth() returns 0 in onCreate

Tags: java, android

I have this code :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    content = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
    ball = (Ball) findViewById(R.id.ball);
    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Log.d("sizes", String.valueOf(content.getWidth()));
    ball.setOnTouchListener(this);

}
```

The problem is that in log it says " 0 ". Can someone explain me what is the lifecycle of an activity and how do you measure a view or for example how do you create a bouncing ball in an activity directly on start. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait for the layout to be drawn before getting the width. When drawn it's measured and the width is saved so you can call `getWidth`. You can add a layout listener to wait for the view to be drawn:

```
final RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
content.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        content.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
        Log.d("sizes", String.valueOf(content.getWidth()));
    }
});
```

Comment: Is this how you do it usually ? if this is the best practice than thank you!

Comment: @КристиянКацаров it's how I always do it and it always have proven to work.